What does "is passing away" mean in "the present form of this world is passing away"; 1 Corinthians 7:31?
1 Corinthians 7:31 ESV

"and those who deal with the world as though they had no dealings with it. For the present form of this world is passing away." [My emphasis]

From whom is the present form of this world passing away? [is passing away/paragei; present; active]
From Matthew 9:9

"As Jesus passed on from there, he saw a man...".

Here Jesus "passed on/paragon" but it does not mean that He stops being Himself in any sense. So is "passing away" the same as "passing on"? [passing on/paragon]
Revelation 21:1

"Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away, and the sea was no more." [passed away/apelthan]

Here aperchomai not parago is used for "passed away". What sort of passing away is parago in 1 Cor 7:31?

That the first earth passed away does not have to mean that it stopped existing, only that it passed out of view, due to the person behind the viewing eyes moved from the old to the new earth. This happens after Jerusalem gets sacked at the end of the holy Millennium. After that people will continue to live on the old earth until radiation caused by too much nuclear wastage makes it too dangerous to continue living here, or the sun explodes into a red giant due to a volatile chain reaction caused by the sun being used as a nuclear wastage dump.

The eleven uses of the verb παράγω (paragó) naturally fall into two categories in the NT:

to go/pass by a reference point, pass by, Matt 9:9, 27, 20:30, Mark 1:16, 2:14, 15:21, John 8:59, 9:1.  Note that these all occur in the gospels and all except Mark 5:21 refer to Jesus.

to go out of existence, pass away, disappear, 1 Cor 7:31, 1 John 2:8, 17.  Note that all these refer to this world or its associated sinful-darkness which is about to pass away.



1 Cor 7:31 - and those using the world, as not using it as their own. For the present form of this world is passing away.
1 John 2:8 - Again, I am writing a new commandment to you, which is true in Him and in you, because the darkness is passing away and the true light already shines.
1 John 2:17 - The world is passing away, along with its desires; but whoever does the will of God remains forever.

The much more frequent verb ἀπέρχομαι (aperchomai) has the basic meaning, "I come or go away from, depart, return, arrive, go after, follow"; and has a more varied set of meanings.  According to BDAG, the relevant meaning in Rev 21;1 is:

to discontinue as a state or condition, eg, of diseases, or fruit, or something else:


Mark 1:42 - And immediately the leprosy departed from him, and he was cleansed.
Luke 5:13 - Jesus reached out His hand and touched the man. “I am willing,” He said. “Be clean!” And immediately the leprosy left him.
Rev 9:12 - The first woe has passed. Behold, two woes are still to follow.
Rev 11:14 - The second woe has passed. Behold, the third woe is coming shortly.
Rev 18:14 - And they will say: “The fruit of your soul’s desire has departed from you; all your luxury and splendor have vanished, never to be seen again.”
Rev 21:1 - Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and earth had passed away, and the sea was no more.
Rev 21:4 - ‘He will wipe away every tear from their eyes,’ and there will be no more death or mourning or crying or pain, for the former things have passed away.”

Thus, it is immediately obvious that the range of meaning of these two verbs overlaps in some cases.  Both are used to describe the temporary nature of the current sinful world by the fact that the current sinful world is passing away.
Indeed, the stated intention of God is to replace the current sinful world (which is passing away) with "a new heaven and a new earth" (Rev 21:1).

Thanks. Looking back I think I did not construct this question as well as I should. But still: 1 Cor 7:31 "is passing away" is present. In your comment 2. you say  "is about to pass away". i.e., no longer present but a prediction about the future. My question then is in what sense is now [present tense] "the present form of this world" passing away"?

i.e., Did Paul believe that the end of the world had started, or, is "is passing away" a reference to the inability of this world to provide a lasting foundation, as in 1 Cor 3:11? A foundation... which is Jesus Christ?

@C.Stroud - the very fact that this world is limited in time means that it is passing away.  That remained true even when Adam sinned
